# White space below footer only in IE

Tags: css, html, wordpress, footer

I am building a Wordpress blog for my company and I picked a theme I thought would go well with our business. I have added widgetized areas to the footer to facilitate easy customization. When the page loads, a weird white space is below the footer, but this only happens in IE. In Chrome, when I am at the bottom and refresh the page, I can see the white space, but it disappears as soon as the page loads.  The page renders correctly in everything but IE. Any help getting rid of this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a live link to the [blog](http://dev.saiedmusic.com).

Comment: I don't think the tag `removing whitespace` belongs here.

Comment: When I look at the source of the page it has tons of script and div tags on the bottom. One of those divs might accidentally get some height or spacing in IE (bug?). Try to see per tag (below the footer) if any of those are causing it.

Comment: Which version(s) of IE?

Comment: Nocholas, you're probably right.

Comment: Allender, I had a couple of extra </div> tags, but I deleted those with no impact.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could try.

1. Remove the `line-height: 1` from the `.fb_reset` class, because the `#fb-root` div is essentially empy this shouldn't render — however IE might get confused.
2. Add an `overflow: hidden` to your `#footer` and `#container` elements.

Comment: Thank you sir! Adding `overflow: hidden` to #container fixed the problem.

Comment: @PeterG -- no worries... glad it helped. If in doubt, always add an `overflow: hidden` (unless you need overflowing content, obviously)

Comment: Adding `overflow:hidden` fixed my IE11 bug. Thanks!