# Unwanted White space in internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, footer

I am working on a site which is perfectly working in chrome and Firefox browsers. But the actual problem is , in internet explorer its showing unwanted extra space at footer. How to adjust the footer without having extra space in all browsers ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code here, and then you can also post a live link.

Comment: Current working site link is 
http://beta.people10.com

Comment: We can't guess your code; please add the relevant code to your post

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Comment: @LiamSorsby no probably this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552588/white-space-below-footer-only-in-ie?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the root of the problem. The problem is because `clear: both` property of your div having id="block-block-18" is not applied in Internet Explorer. Using 'clearfix' is the solution. Many posts on the method exist on stackoverflow. Please search the one that suits you.

Comment: Hi abhijith, i have removed clear:both attribute and added overflow: hidden to main container. The issue is resolved now. Thanks .

Comment: hi syam kumar where you removed clear:both prop