# White space below footer only in all versions of I.E

Tags: html, css

On my clients [website](http://www.4fj.com.fj/get-involved/take-the-pledge/) in all versions of I.E. I can see a white big whitespace I have searched everything divs for their height, display type, float, and also line heights but nothing seems to work for me.

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552588/white-space-below-footer-only-in-ie) which has smiliar or same issue. He managed to solve it. I have already used what he used but still didn't resolved yet.

I have also addded a doctype for IE no luck. I' am using I.E. 10 to view my site currently.

More information
I have notices that it only appears after the LIKE and TWEET.
[image]
Please help.

Comment: is it possible to show a screenshot showing problem ? can not see what is wrong on IE 9, 10. Please note on IE 8 your site looks destroyed, what version of IE are we talking about ?

Comment: I' am using I.E. 10 to view my site currently.

Comment: Ok. and where is your blank space ? which page ? which location ?

Comment: Tested with IE11, FF and Chrome and all look virtually the same. I even navigated to other pages to see if there we any differences. You might have to clear your browser cache or press shift F5 to force a page refresh.

Comment: This is the page http://www.4fj.com.fj/get-involved/take-the-pledge/

Comment: layout.css line 444 = padding: 70px 0; You need to define the bottom padding i.e. padding: 70px 0 20px 0;

Answer (score 0):

can you try removing vertical-align property in you css for HTML. this should solve you issue.

Comment: it would be helpful, if you can post it on jfiddle

Comment: hi, I have tried that but it doesn't work. Thanks for contributing.

Comment: @NavneilNaicker I seriously would like to help but as for I do not see the problem.

Comment: I have edited my question with the screenshot but I think that not much gona help you. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I was not actually was able to find the correct solution for my problem but I had made workout of solve this issue. The problem was on AddThis LIKE AND TWEET Feature. Something was causing problem from it. What I did I made them hide in all versions of I.E.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a page with no vertical scroll then try setting the position of your footer as fixed, top:100% and margin-top:"minus the height of your footer", this will do the trick!

Comment: or else try setting the position as absolute! this worked for me!